# How do I build an SdkMesh with Textures and MeshConvert.exe?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, directx-11, direct3d

I need to build an sdkmesh file similar to Tiny.sdkmesh that comes with DirectX SDK.

I have the mesh file `base.obj`

And I have the texture in `textures/base.jpg`

I'm running `meshconvert.exe` with the following command line

`meshconvert.exe base.obj -n -op -tb`

It generates a `base.sdkmesh` but it has no texture file

I tried saving the `jpeg` texture as a `dds` file using paint.net

When I render my model, it comes out all black. But when I render the `tiny.sdkmesh` model, it comes out textured.

Can someone help explain this undocumented tool and procedure?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use that format. If your mesh doesn't include skeletal animation then consider using obj format instead. For more complex meshes there's FBX format and it's SDK

Comment: The DXUT in SDK doesn't import OBJ files, does it?

Comment: It doesn't but you can find wrappers online for doing so. Even Microsoft recommends not to use that format including x files too

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks, do you have any references to these wrappers by chance?

Comment: Google it. Here's one I know: https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `meshconvert` is part of the [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/wiki/Meshconvert), so unless you specifically need legacy .X file support (which you don't since you are using Wavefront OBJ) you should use that one instead of the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

The default behavior of `meshconvert` is to take the texture file names from your Wavefront OBJ's `mtl` file and embed them as `.dds` versions of the same file (so `texture.jpg` is stored as `texture.dds`). You can generate the `dds` using the `texconv` tool in the [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) project. You can also tell the latest `meshconvert` to leave the filenames alone using the `-nodds` switch.

You can also create `SDKMESH` files from Autodesk FBX files using the [DirectX SDK Samples Content Exporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter). This exporter will 'cook' the textures as part of the export process as well.

If you have a `sdkmesh` and you are trying to figure out what texture references it has in it, try using the [sdkmeshdump](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/sdkmeshdump.cpp) console utility to see what's in it.

> Disclaimer: `SDKMESH` is really only intended as a learning format used in DirectX samples. You can use it in your project, but you will most likely want to develop your own runtime container format if your engine/project becomes sophisticated. It mostly has the value of existing, so YMMV.

See [DirectXMesh wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/wiki/Geometry-formats#sdkmesh) and the [DirectX SDK Content Exporter wiki](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter/wiki/SDKMESH)

> If you are using DXUT, you should use the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT). `sdkmesh` is also supported by the *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and [DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12)

Comment: I see, are textures stored as Material data in .sdkmesh files, or is material not the same thing as texture?

Comment: The ``sdkmesh`` file is binary that contains the VB, the IB, and some metadata like a material definition. It does not include the texture itself, only the filename of the texture. At runtime you need the ``sdkmesh`` and any texture files it references. See [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Media/Meshes/Tiny).